# Libclang tokenKinds

Tags: clang, token, llvm-clang, libclang

Where can I find the token kinds in libclang?

for example I know these token kinds exists:
eof, r_paren, l_paren, r_brace, l_brace

Where can I find the rest of the token kinds?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In libclang, the token kinds are `CXToken_Punctuation`, `CXToken_Keyword`, `CXToken_Identifier`, `CXToken_Literal`, and `CXToken_Comment`. ([link](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__LEX.html#gaf63e37eee4280e2c039829af24bbc201))

In clang, the list of token kinds can be found by preprocessing the file [clang/Basic/TokenKinds.def](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/include/clang/Basic/TokenKinds.def) after making the definition `#define TOK(X) X`. Doing this gives me the following list:

`unknown`,
`eof`,
`eod`,
`code_completion`,
`comment`,
`identifier`,
`raw_identifier`,
`numeric_constant`,
`char_constant`,
`wide_char_constant`,
`utf8_char_constant`,
`utf16_char_constant`,
`utf32_char_constant`,
`string_literal`,
`wide_string_literal`,
`angle_string_literal`,
`utf8_string_literal`,
`utf16_string_literal`,
`utf32_string_literal`,
`l_square`,
`r_square`,
`l_paren`,
`r_paren`,
`l_brace`,
`r_brace`,
`period`,
`ellipsis`,
`amp`,
`ampamp`,
`ampequal`,
`star`,
`starequal`,
`plus`,
`plusplus`,
`plusequal`,
`minus`,
`arrow`,
`minusminus`,
`minusequal`,
`tilde`,
`exclaim`,
`exclaimequal`,
`slash`,
`slashequal`,
`percent`,
`percentequal`,
`less`,
`lessless`,
`lessequal`,
`lesslessequal`,
`greater`,
`greatergreater`,
`greaterequal`,
`greatergreaterequal`,
`caret`,
`caretequal`,
`pipe`,
`pipepipe`,
`pipeequal`,
`question`,
`colon`,
`semi`,
`equal`,
`equalequal`,
`comma`,
`hash`,
`hashhash`,
`hashat`,
`periodstar`,
`arrowstar`,
`coloncolon`,
`at`,
`lesslessless`,
`greatergreatergreater`,
`kw_auto`,
`kw_break`,
`kw_case`,
`kw_char`,
`kw_const`,
`kw_continue`,
`kw_default`,
`kw_do`,
`kw_double`,
`kw_else`,
`kw_enum`,
`kw_extern`,
`kw_float`,
`kw_for`,
`kw_goto`,
`kw_if`,
`kw_inline`,
`kw_int`,
`kw_long`,
`kw_register`,
`kw_restrict`,
`kw_return`,
`kw_short`,
`kw_signed`,
`kw_sizeof`,
`kw_static`,
`kw_struct`,
`kw_switch`,
`kw_typedef`,
`kw_union`,
`kw_unsigned`,
`kw_void`,
`kw_volatile`,
`kw_while`,
`kw__Alignas`,
`kw__Alignof`,
`kw__Atomic`,
`kw__Bool`,
`kw__Complex`,
`kw__Generic`,
`kw__Imaginary`,
`kw__Noreturn`,
`kw__Static_assert`,
`kw__Thread_local`,
`kw___func__`,
`kw___objc_yes`,
`kw___objc_no`,
`kw_asm`,
`kw_bool`,
`kw_catch`,
`kw_class`,
`kw_const_cast`,
`kw_delete`,
`kw_dynamic_cast`,
`kw_explicit`,
`kw_export`,
`kw_false`,
`kw_friend`,
`kw_mutable`,
`kw_namespace`,
`kw_new`,
`kw_operator`,
`kw_private`,
`kw_protected`,
`kw_public`,
`kw_reinterpret_cast`,
`kw_static_cast`,
`kw_template`,
`kw_this`,
`kw_throw`,
`kw_true`,
`kw_try`,
`kw_typename`,
`kw_typeid`,
`kw_using`,
`kw_virtual`,
`kw_wchar_t`,
`kw_alignas`,
`kw_alignof`,
`kw_char16_t`,
`kw_char32_t`,
`kw_constexpr`,
`kw_decltype`,
`kw_noexcept`,
`kw_nullptr`,
`kw_static_assert`,
`kw_thread_local`,
`kw_concept`,
`kw_requires`,
`kw_co_await`,
`kw_co_return`,
`kw_co_yield`,
`kw__Decimal32`,
`kw__Decimal64`,
`kw__Decimal128`,
`kw___null`,
`kw___alignof`,
`kw___attribute`,
`kw___builtin_choose_expr`,
`kw___builtin_offsetof`,
`kw___builtin_types_compatible_p`,
`kw___builtin_va_arg`,
`kw___extension__`,
`kw___imag`,
`kw___int128`,
`kw___label__`,
`kw___real`,
`kw___thread`,
`kw___FUNCTION__`,
`kw___PRETTY_FUNCTION__`,
`kw___auto_type`,
`kw_typeof`,
`kw___FUNCDNAME__`,
`kw___FUNCSIG__`,
`kw_L__FUNCTION__`,
`kw___is_interface_class`,
`kw___is_sealed`,
`kw___is_destructible`,
`kw___is_nothrow_destructible`,
`kw___is_nothrow_assignable`,
`kw___is_constructible`,
`kw___is_nothrow_constructible`,
`kw___has_nothrow_assign`,
`kw___has_nothrow_move_assign`,
`kw___has_nothrow_copy`,
`kw___has_nothrow_constructor`,
`kw___has_trivial_assign`,
`kw___has_trivial_move_assign`,
`kw___has_trivial_copy`,
`kw___has_trivial_constructor`,
`kw___has_trivial_move_constructor`,
`kw___has_trivial_destructor`,
`kw___has_virtual_destructor`,
`kw___is_abstract`,
`kw___is_base_of`,
`kw___is_class`,
`kw___is_convertible_to`,
`kw___is_empty`,
`kw___is_enum`,
`kw___is_final`,
`kw___is_literal`,
`kw___is_pod`,
`kw___is_polymorphic`,
`kw___is_trivial`,
`kw___is_union`,
`kw___is_trivially_constructible`,
`kw___is_trivially_copyable`,
`kw___is_trivially_assignable`,
`kw___underlying_type`,
`kw___is_lvalue_expr`,
`kw___is_rvalue_expr`,
`kw___is_arithmetic`,
`kw___is_floating_point`,
`kw___is_integral`,
`kw___is_complete_type`,
`kw___is_void`,
`kw___is_array`,
`kw___is_function`,
`kw___is_reference`,
`kw___is_lvalue_reference`,
`kw___is_rvalue_reference`,
`kw___is_fundamental`,
`kw___is_object`,
`kw___is_scalar`,
`kw___is_compound`,
`kw___is_pointer`,
`kw___is_member_object_pointer`,
`kw___is_member_function_pointer`,
`kw___is_member_pointer`,
`kw___is_const`,
`kw___is_volatile`,
`kw___is_standard_layout`,
`kw___is_signed`,
`kw___is_unsigned`,
`kw___is_same`,
`kw___is_convertible`,
`kw___array_rank`,
`kw___array_extent`,
`kw___private_extern__`,
`kw___module_private__`,
`kw___declspec`,
`kw___cdecl`,
`kw___stdcall`,
`kw___fastcall`,
`kw___thiscall`,
`kw___vectorcall`,
`kw___forceinline`,
`kw___unaligned`,
`kw___super`,
`kw___global`,
`kw___local`,
`kw___constant`,
`kw___private`,
`kw___generic`,
`kw___kernel`,
`kw___read_only`,
`kw___write_only`,
`kw___read_write`,
`kw___builtin_astype`,
`kw_vec_step`,
`kw___builtin_omp_required_simd_align`,
`kw_pipe`,
`kw___pascal`,
`kw___vector`,
`kw___pixel`,
`kw___bool`,
`kw_half`,
`kw___bridge`,
`kw___bridge_transfer`,
`kw___bridge_retained`,
`kw___bridge_retain`,
`kw___covariant`,
`kw___contravariant`,
`kw___kindof`,
`kw__Nonnull`,
`kw__Nullable`,
`kw__Null_unspecified`,
`kw___ptr64`,
`kw___ptr32`,
`kw___sptr`,
`kw___uptr`,
`kw___w64`,
`kw___uuidof`,
`kw___try`,
`kw___finally`,
`kw___leave`,
`kw___int64`,
`kw___if_exists`,
`kw___if_not_exists`,
`kw___single_inheritance`,
`kw___multiple_inheritance`,
`kw___virtual_inheritance`,
`kw___interface`,
`kw___builtin_convertvector`,
`kw___unknown_anytype`,
`annot_cxxscope`,
`annot_typename`,
`annot_template_id`,
`annot_primary_expr`,
`annot_decltype`,
`annot_pragma_unused`,
`annot_pragma_vis`,
`annot_pragma_pack`,
`annot_pragma_parser_crash`,
`annot_pragma_captured`,
`annot_pragma_dump`,
`annot_pragma_msstruct`,
`annot_pragma_align`,
`annot_pragma_weak`,
`annot_pragma_weakalias`,
`annot_pragma_redefine_extname`,
`annot_pragma_fp_contract`,
`annot_pragma_ms_pointers_to_members`,
`annot_pragma_ms_vtordisp`,
`annot_pragma_ms_pragma`,
`annot_pragma_opencl_extension`,
`annot_pragma_openmp`,
`annot_pragma_openmp_end`,
`annot_pragma_loop_hint`,
`annot_module_include`,
`annot_module_begin`,
`annot_module_end`

Comment: Am parsing C/C++ source code. Do you think using these token will give me the ability to determine whether or not a declared? For example in the ASTs I can detect whether or not a function declaration exists. Again thank you for your answer.